# css float not behaving in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, css-float

Hi I know IE7 css float issues have been asked here a few times but I still can't resolve my issue.

Please have a look at [this page](http://www.suzephotography.com.au/dev/index.php?option=com_myblog&Itemid=21). I'm using IE9 in IE7 mode and have changed the widths of the divs and the items inside them, checked the clear:lefts and the heights but the main div won't float to the left of the nav.

Can anyone spot the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking out the `#main { clear: left; }` and removing the `.narrow#main { margin-top: -40px; }` did it for me.

At least, it seems to work in IE9's IE7 mode.

Comment: Excellent thanks, yes that fixed it! It was the clear:inherit; property in #main.narrow I changed it to clear:none and disabled the margin as you suggested, many thanks :)